# Microservice deployment using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to develop a Spring Cloud microservice and deploying into AWS cloud using Elastic Beanstalk. When I am searching deployment options I found that deployment environment of Beanstalk. I have a little confusion here. Can I deploy my microservice using Elastic Beanstalk without launching EC2 machine?

Here I am approaching only to Elastic Beanstalk service. Deploying microservice using Elastic Beanstalk without launching EC2 is possible?

I am a beginner in the AWS world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy your microservices. When you use Elastic Beanstalk, in the backend Elastic Beanstalk creates the required EC2 instances and Load balancers to run and deploy your application. Hence you don't need to create an EC2 instance. I would recommend you to follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html), which walks you through to launch a sample Multi Docker application.

Also, I would recommend you to research [ECS/Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html)  service which has more capabilities for hosting a Microservices application.

Comment: Ok , I understood . Thank you for your response Mr. Sudheerchamarthi.

Comment: Till today I'm still fighting with how to make internal Comms between microservices without using API gateway and on private network